# canvas draw bitmap overrides drawn path

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a problem with canvas I have two options either to draw with a paint or to add an image but when I choose to add an image after drawing the drawing is gone but when I choose drawing again and start to draw the previous drawing show up and remove the image.

```
public class DrawCanvas extends View {
Bitmap bitmap;
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path;
ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Path> undo = new ArrayList<>();
final Paint mBackgroundPaint;
ArrayList<Emotion> emotions;
private boolean mDrawingEnabled = true;
float currentX = 0, currentY = 0;

public DrawCanvas(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.launcher);
    paint.setAntiAlias(false);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(30f);
    emotions = new ArrayList<>();
    path = new Path();
    mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
    mBackgroundPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    if (mDrawingEnabled ) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
    else{
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, currentX, currentY, null);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent){
    int xPos =(int) motionEvent.getX(), yPos =(int) motionEvent.getY();

    final int action = motionEvent.getAction();
    if (mDrawingEnabled){
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                paths.add(path);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

    }
    else {
        final float me_x = motionEvent.getX();
        final float me_y = motionEvent.getY();

        switch ( action ) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                currentX = me_x;
                currentY = me_y;
                break;
        }
    }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}

public void undo(){
    if (paths.size()>0){
        undo.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
    }
}

public void redo(){
    if (undo.size()>0){
        paths.add(undo.remove(undo.size()-1));
    }
}

final void enableDrawing() { mDrawingEnabled = true; }

final void disableDrawing() { mDrawingEnabled = false; }

public void changeBrushColor(int color){
    paint.setColor(color);
}

public void changeBrushSize(int size){
    paint.setStrokeWidth(size);
}
```

}

[here is the drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eunDO.png)

[and when I add image clears the drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGI9g.png)

I want to keep the drawn path alongside the image.

Comment: onDraw calls every frame. You need call canvas.drawPath(path, paint); every time.

Comment: @DmitriyP it will work for the path but the bitmap also disappears when I try to paint again